# ASP.NET5 log4net

Tags: asp.net-web-api, log4net

I'm trying to convert a small Web API project to ASP.NET5 Web API, but I'm having some troubles getting log4net to work.
The official log4net doesn't seem to support .NET core yet, so instead I'm using log4net-core-pcl (https://github.com/chlowell/log4net/tree/log4net-core-pcl), which should support Core 
Though I get the following error:

DNX Core 5.0 error NU1002: The dependency log4net 1.2.10 in project WebApplication1 does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0.

I did the following:

1) Create a new ASP.NET 5 Web API project

2) Download the log4net-core-pcl from https://github.com/chlowell/log4net/tree/log4net-core-pcl

3) Add (Add existing project) the log4net-core-pcl project to my solution

4) Create reference to log4net-core-pcl

5) Compile

Now it seems like it's still pulling log4net fra Nuget instead of using the log4net-core-pcl project I've added to the solution, so do I need to reference the log4net-core-pcl in a different way?

Any ideas?

Comment: What is step 4? You should add a project reference then.

Comment: Yes, create reference to  log4net-core-pcl

Comment: I am not how does you added reference in ASP.NET5 but I just want to share some information...

1. For adding reference please add in project.json file inside dependencies tag.
2. And please add log through your code using this library.

Answer (score 0):

This an old unanswered question. The newest version of log4net now supports .NET Core. I just put together a blog post showing how to make log4net work with .NET Core v1.0. With log4net 2.0.7 it supports NetStandard 1.3 but you have to manually setup the configs.

https://stackify.com/making-log4net-net-core-work/